# Redis sort db values by keys

Tags: python, redis

My redis keys are stored as milisecond. So a sample key 111111111 UNIX timestamp.
How can I sort values by ordering the keys?

I need to reverse timestamps so keys print the vals per key

```
import redis
red = redis.Redis(host='localhost', db=0)
keys = red.keys()
vals = red.mget(keys)
kv = zip(keys, vals)
kv.reverse()
print(vals)
```

Comment: Do you mean on the server side? Notice `keys()` command is very risky since it returns all the keys in one blocking call

Comment: no matter ...  .which was the async one